# How do i view or access java docs offline?

Tags: java, javadoc

I downloaded java docs or what i think was java docs from oracle. But i'm not really sure how to summon all that drama without going online or using eclipse.

By the way, I use jedit. (Yeah, baby. Hurts so good). I'm a student, and i need to limit my distractions and going online is my enemy right now. Any help would help. Thanks.

Comment: You may also consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928271/java-help-documentation-in-chm-format that features offline search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your webbrowser and open up the `index.html` page that's probably in the root directory of the `docs`.

Comment: Thank you, Jon Lin.  You are a gentlemen and a scholar. I will tell tales of your kindness for years to come.

Comment: There's this upvote button that could really show your thanks. :))

Comment: Gentlemen, ladies, and scholars can be rewarded by upvoting ;)

Comment: you can also accept an answer to show your thanks. Click on the checkmark near the vote buttons. That also shows other users, that your question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Download Javadoc in HTML Help format for offline use. For Windows users only.
http://www.allimant.org/javadoc/

Comment: Contains offline HTML Help for download of Oracle Java Tutorial also!